# los logos se mueven

Tags: css, html5, imagen

```css
.size {
        width: 80px ; 
        height: auto ;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
 <!-- links a las redes sociales de la pagina -->
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="Imagenes/Iconos/Facebook Logo.png" alt="Facebook" class="size"></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=es"><img src="Imagenes/Iconos/Twitter Logo.png" alt="Twitter" class="size"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="Imagenes/Iconos/Youtube Logo.png" alt="Youtube" class="size"></a>
                </div>
```

Al pasar el mouse uno de los logos de redes sociales que tengo en mi pagina, se separan; como si fuera "abran paso". Cómo hago para que se queden quietos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes tener algun otro componenete que con una animacion,que se activa con el hover, o tambien puede ser elemento padre, asegurate de bloquear todas las animaciones que tengas en css

Comment: Ahora me di cuenta que, no se por que tenia un padding al hacer hover, gracias

Comment: de nada, cualquier otro duda que tengas no dudes en prenguntar